# dotnet json webservice for vfp program to pass data as solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-foxpro

I am searching for a solution to pass a large dataset from visual foxpro(vfp) to a .net web service.  The data is personal information such as names, address, phone numbers, etc. with 7 more columns containing id's and other parameters.

We tried cursor to xml dataset but the file size is very large. So my idea is to pass json formatted string. We need to accommodate up to 1 million rows of data

I found this solution on the web for json webservice.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/JsonWebServiceJQuery.aspx Can this work for such large datasets?  Is there anything better suited for my situation

I found this class for VFP 
http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/spsblog/2008/12/19/VisualFoxproJSONClassUpdate.aspx
which promises to do what is needed  as far as converting to json format.  Should this work? Is there anything else I am missing here?

Edit:
As it turns out parsing a json string back to vfp object is a very time intensive process and we will be using xml data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to push or pull up to a million records of data such as describing is bound for issues of performance, tying up resources, bad packets / data, etc... I would suggest pushing the data out in smaller chunks so if any problems, you can re-submit a given batch before you find out if fails on record 999,990 and need to send the entire thing again.